# IOS to REST-ful MVC Api Service - [Get] works, but parameters don't reach server with [Post]

Tags: ios, rest, post, asp.net-mvc-4

I think the title explains it.  I can reach the Get functions on my api controllers just fine.  I can reach the Post method, but my parameter (macAddress) is null.  I've tried many variations of this code in xcode:

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",baseURL,controller]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString *postString = @"macAddress=testestest";
NSData *myRequestData = [ NSData dataWithBytes: [ postString UTF8String ] length: [ postString length ] ];
[request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
```

and the controller:

```
    public String Post([FromBody]string macAddress)
    {
        //......
    }
```

(I'm aware that I'm using synchronous requests and nil response/errors, just trying to figure out this aspect)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just quick comment on the code. String could be converted to data in a simpler way - [body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]

Comment: Btw code looks good. I have similar one in my app, it works perfect :)

Comment: You need to instal sniffer and check outgoing traffic from the client. I do not think that issue on a client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your *postString without the [NSString stringWithFormat method].  I use the following code with my own restful API.

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"rsdevicetoken"];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"token=%@&active=%@&draw=%@&result=%@&message=%@",deviceToken,allNotify, draw, results, message];
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/updateSubscriptions"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", data);
```

Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: I set up my request to mimic yours, as well as changed the string to 
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"macAddress=%@",@"testestest"];
Unfortunately I am still getting null on the server side :(

Comment: Did it work with it like mine? Try it like this NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"macAddress=testtesttest"] I think that might solve your problem.

Comment: This is what I have on now, and still getting null server-side
NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"macAddress=testestest"];
    NSData *myRequestData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];
    
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

Comment: I'm at a loss, but I will keep working to help you.  Try using the URLWithString method...maybe it's in your URL.

Comment: can I ask what your server side method looks like?

Comment: It's a node.js server with a mongodb backend.  I set my API up to use Express.js and talk to the node server which posts the data into a mongo database.  That may be the issue.  You are using C# and ASP.NET for your backend.

Answer (score 0):

It's a wild guess but if your `macAddress` post param has the following format: `01:23:45:67:89:ab` you need to url encode the ':' to '%3A'.